# How to add break tag inside content_for tag in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my layout file I am having a content_for tag for saying thanking you. I want to give line break between CEO and The Sadly Design Team, as well as The Happy design team. How to do this? While using < br/> i am getting syntax error.

layout.html.erb

```
<p class="no-margin" style="padding:10px 0 0;">
                    <%= content_for?(:thanking) ? 'CEO,' ' The Sadly Design Team' : "Sincerely, 'The Happy design team " %>
 </p>
```

Comment: HAve u tried giving a newline character "\n"

Comment: Ya I tried like this  <%= content_for?(:thanking) ? yield(:thanking)  : 'Sincerely,' /n + 'The Happy design team ' %> But it does not work.

Comment: "\n" will just add a new line in the HTML output - but browsers will ignores the new line. You need to add a line break tag <br> (or perhaps better - put the two elements in span tags and use display:block;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
<%= (content_for?(:thanking) ? "CEO,<br/>The Sadly Design Team" : "Sincerely,<br/>The Happy design team").html_safe %>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Take a look at the approach by ReggieB, it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% if content_for?(:thanking) %>
CEO,<br>
The Sadly Design Team
<% else %>
Sincerely,<br> 
The Happy design team
<% end %>
```